# Transparent and OS-agnostic path handling in Java

Tags: java, cross-platform, file-handling

I am developing a graphical installer for our application. Since none of the available installer generators meet the requirements and constraints, I am building it from scratch.

The installer is supposed to run on several operating systems, and therefore the path handling needs to be OS-agnostic. I have written the following small utility for this purpose:

```
public class Path {
  private Path() {
  }

  public static String join(String... pathElements) {
    return ListEnhancer.wrap(Arrays.asList(pathElements)).
      mkString(File.separator);
  }

  public static String concatOsSpecific(String path, String element) {
    return path + File.separator + element;
  }

  public static String concatOsAgnostic(String path, String element) {
    return path + "/" + element;
  }

  public static String makeOsAgnostic(String path) {
    return path.replace(File.separator, "/");
  }

  public static String makeOsSpecific(String path) {
    return new File(path).getAbsolutePath();
  }

  public static String fileName(String path) {
    return new File(path).getName();
  }
}
```

Now my code is littered with `Path.*Agnostic` and `Path.*Specific` calls in many places. As is apparent, this is very error-prone and not transparent at all.

What approach should I take to make the path handling transparent and less error-prone? Do there exist any utilities/libraries that already address this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

To exemplify what I mean, here is some code I wrote a while ago. (Offtopic: Forgive the long-ish method. The code is in initial stages, and will be undergoing some heavy refactoring soon.)

Some context: `ApplicationContext` is an object that stores the installation data. That includes several paths such as `installationRootDirectory`, `installationDirectory` etc. The defaults for these are specified when creating an installer, and hence are always stored in OS-agnostic formats.

```
@Override
protected void initializeComponents() {
  super.initializeComponents();
  choosePathLabel = new JLabel("Please select the installation path:");
  final ApplicationContext c = installer.getAppContext();
  pathTextField = new JTextField(
    Path.makeOsSpecific(c.getInstallationDirectory()));
  browseButton = new JButton("Browse", 
    new ImageIcon("resources/images/browse.png"));
  browseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
      fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
      fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
      int choice = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(installer);
      String selectedInstallationRootDir = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().
        getPath();
      if (choice == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        c.setInstallationRootDirectory(
          Path.makeOsAgnostic(selectedInstallationRootDir));
        pathTextField.setText(Path.makeOsSpecific(c.getInstallationDirectory()));
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Separating paths with `/` works surprisingly well on Windows. Aside from that, why do you need the Agnostic versions at all?

Comment: @Mat, I know that. Here are some cases: 1. `File#getAbsolutePath` returns a string with OS-specific separator. 2. `System.getProperty(<something that returns a path>)` returns a string with OS-specific separator. 3. I need to read from and write to text-boxes in some installation panels, and when being rendered to the user, the paths need to be in OS-specific formats.

Comment: Sure. So what are the *Agnostic things used for?

Comment: @Mat, let me add a code example in my question.

Comment: Is displaying the same separator is a requirement? (e.g. using `\` for all OSs). If not, just have a small utility to determine the not-supported separator, and replace it just before writing to the FS. that way you're not forcing the user to do anything "OS specific"

Comment: @Asaf, yes, that's a requirement.

Comment: @missingfaktor OK, so replace it in the view (e.g. have a `DocumentListner` on the textfield, which replaces it as text is added to the `Document`). WDYT?

Comment: i still don't understand.  why do you need the os agnostic paths?

Comment: @Asaf, interesting. I think the existing approach is cleaner.

Comment: @jtahlborn, I have written a very elaborate description in my question. I added more description in comments. Then I added an example in my question. How can I make this any more clear?

Comment: I am surprised by the puzzled looks of people here. Have you never felt a need for cleaner path handling?

Comment: let me re-phrase my question.  as far as i can tell, you never need the os-agnostic versions.  if you instantiate a File with the os-agnostic version, it will be automatically converted to the os-specific format.  after that, you just use the normal File ops an always work with the os-specific formats.  no need for any custom code.

Comment: cleaner? I guess it's a matter of taste. I'd prefer 1 `DocumentListener` (and maybe + 1 `JTextField` subclass). YMMV.

Comment: but, this code is less clean.  there is no need for anything other than normal File operations.

Comment: C++ has `boost::filesystem::path`. C# has `System.IO.Path`. And I just discovered while googling that Java 7 is also adding a new `Path` class to `java.nio` package. So there are plenty people who need it. I am not trying anything unnecessarily adventurous. Now if I manage to get hold on the source of `Path` in Java 7, I'll add it to my utils.

Comment: @jtahlborn, please read the edit to my question. `ApplicationContext#<path-values>` and the UI rendering are two of the cases that necessitate what I am looking for.

Comment: @jtahlborn, If I understand correctly, the OP is asking for a clean way to _present_ the same separator, regardless of the current OS.

Comment: am i missing something?  ui rendering is os-specific.  when loading from your app context, just use `new File()`.  you are making this much harder than it needs to be.  also, jdk 7 Path does not change anything, it just makes it easier to have virtual filesystems.

Comment: (Adding to my previous comment) Nope, the source isn't unfortunately available. I'll go with what John suggested below.

Comment: @jtahlborn, why don't you use the example code in my question, and show me how it can be made less hard in your opinion?

Comment: @JohnGardner, if no better answer comes up until tomorrow, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or you could introduce 2 new classes:

```
class OsSpecificPath implements FilePathInterface
{
      String path;

      OsAgnosticPath toAgnosticPath();

      OsSpecificPath concat( OsSpecificPath otherPath );

      // from IFilePath
      getFile();

     ... etc
}
```

and

```
class OsAgnosticPath implements FilePathInterface
{
      String path;

      OsSpecificPath toOsSpecificPath();

      OsAgnosticPath concat( OsAgnosticPath otherPath );

      // from IFilePath
      getFile();

     ... etc
}
```

each wrap a path however they need to.

each method could then have methods to convert to the other type of path, but instead of a "stringly-typed" solution where everything is a string and can be misused, you'd have 2 strongly typed classes that can't be incorrectly passed around.

Anything that doesn't care about the type of path would use `FilePathInterface`, anything that needs to operate on specific kinds of paths would use those types specificly.  `FilePathInterface` could hypothetically have both `toAgnosticPath` and `toOsSpecificPath` in the interface if really necessary...

Comment: +1 for being less error-prone. However the conversions are still manual and code would be just as littered.

Comment: they might not *need* to be manual, though.  Both classes could implement a single interface, like `IFilePath` or something, and then each class knows how to create File objects based on its own path style.  you'd then just pass around IFilePath objects everywhere, and hide all of those conversions inside the classes themselves.  Yes, at some point, like displaying them in text boxes, you're probably going to need to do some manual conversion, but everywhere else you shouldn't...

Comment: Marked your answer as correct. A sidenote: This is a Java question, so please follow the Java conventions for method and type names. (Method names should be in lower camelcase, and Java interfaces do not follow the `I-` convention.)

Comment: I want to thank you again for this answer. I reworked my API following the idea you suggested, and I found out a couple of bugs in my code that I might have missed otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're going for, but usually when I need to do something path-related in an OS-independent Java program, I always use Strings to pass paths around instead of Files, and I always do the following two things:

Whenever I am building a String path, I always use `/` as the file separator

Whenever I use a String path to create a File or save it as text somewhere, I always make the following calls prior to using the path:

```
String fSep = System.getProperty("file.separator);
String path = ... //might be built from scratch, might be passed in from somewhere
path = path.replace("/",fSep).replace("\\",fSep);
```

This seems to work well regardless of whether the path gets built on the local machine or if it gets passed in from a different machine on the network with a different OS, provided that I intend to use the path on the local machine.  If you plan to pass the path between different OS'es via networking, just be careful that your own code is consistent.

EDIT

Wow... somehow my answer got mangled up and the code formatting didn't work as initially intended...

Comment: I also replace, just before writing to the file system.

Answer (score 0):

I would make my own MyFile object that extends or wraps java.util.File. Then make sure all your code uses this object instead of java.io.File. In here you would be doing the OS checks and calling methods to clean up the file name. The rest of your code would be 'clean'.

Comment: I'm assuming he means java.io.File.

Answer (score 0):

You never need to convert *back* to os-agnostic.  here are the conversions to os-specific:

```
public class Path {
  private Path() {
  }

  public static String concat(String path, String element) {
    return new File(path, element).getPath();
  }

  public static String makeOsSpecific(String path) {
    return new File(path).getAbsolutePath();
  }

  public static String fileName(String path) {
    return new File(path).getName();
  }
}
```

Your sample:

```
@Override
protected void initializeComponents() {
  super.initializeComponents();
  choosePathLabel = new JLabel("Please select the installation path:");
  final ApplicationContext c = installer.getAppContext();
  pathTextField = new JTextField(
    Path.makeOsSpecific(c.getInstallationDirectory()));
  browseButton = new JButton("Browse", 
    new ImageIcon("resources/images/browse.png"));
  browseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
      fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
      fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
      int choice = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(installer);
      String selectedInstallationRootDir = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().
        getPath();
      if (choice == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        c.setInstallationRootDirectory(selectedInstallationRootDir);
        pathTextField.setText(Path.makeOsSpecific(c.getInstallationDirectory()));
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: There is an error in your example. `File#getPath` method returns OS-specific path string, whereas I need to store paths in OS-agnostic form in `ApplicationContext`. So `c.setInstallationDirectory(selectedInstallationRootDir)` is wrong.

Comment: @missingfaktor - _why_ do you need to store them in os-agnostic format?  that is the question i keep asking and you have not yet answered.

Comment: I have already answered it in one of the comments in this thread. Anyway here here we go again: `Installer` objects are created using this API I am designing. These objects need to specify several paths during their installation, and the paths are stored as strings. The `Installer` object will be written only once and will need to be functional regardless of OS. Now if I store these paths in formats specific to some OS, that would create a problem, wouldn't it?

Comment: @missingfaktor - my understanding of the ui code that you included is that is part of the installer shown to the user when running your installer, is that not correct?  in which case, you would never need the os-agnostic paths, only the os-specific ones for the current os.  what am i missing?

Comment: I give up. I think I have explained everything in sufficient detail by now, and I no more care to explain my case any further.

Comment: @missingfaktor - the problem with explanations is that you have a lot of context which makes the small bit of information you have given make sense to you.  unfortunately, this small window of info doesn't make sense to outsiders.  many times people try to solve the wrong problem.  i think that is the case here, unfortunately, i can't seem to find the root problem, so i can't help you solve it.  the root problem is "why do you need os-agnostic paths" (other than the initial state of the installer).  once you start the installation process, you should only need os-specific paths.